# No visual effects with Intel HD 3000 on Ubuntu 11.10, no compiz, no ubuntu-tweak etc

Tags: 11.10, compiz, intel, effects

I have just come back to PCs after about a decade of avoiding Windows the Apple way.I have a Sony Vaio Z series which has one of the Sandybridge i5 processors which includes the HD3000 graphics. I decided to remove Windows and Stick Ubuntu on it, after a bit of a struggle getting everything to work, all seems to be good except that I cannot get any of the visual effects to do anything. With Compiz, I have the option to change various settings but altering them makes no difference, similarly Ubuntu-tweak does nothing. I am using Gnome as opposed to Unity (which I think looks terrible!) but have also tried Gnome Shell and using Gnome-tweak in that environment I was able to make a few basic changes to things like positions of window buttons etc but nothing more than that.
I typed this into terminal:

/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Everything came back with a 'yes' next to it, including Unity 3d support. Any help with enabling effects would be very much appreciated, thank you - oh, and go easy on me, I'm new to this!

Comment: When you use Gnome-Shell, do you go into the standard shell, or the fallback mode? Because if you enter the standard Gnome 3 interface, you ARE using the compositing effects. Gnome doesn't use compiz, by the way, so unless you are using Unity or gnome-fallback, I wouldn't worry about Compiz too much.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can figure out, it's the standard shell, I get all the features like the expanding dock/launcher type thing on the right and the various different features. The problem is that when I try to add any themes using the gnome-tweak program, the drop down menu for themes is greyed out and has an orange exclamation mark triangle next to it. I have checked that the themes I'm trying to install are in the themes folder but I can't seem to get anywhere with it.

Comment: Sorry, I should say the dock/launcher is on the left - it's been a long day!

Comment: So you are having a problem with Gnome-Tweak. You have to install the user theme extension before that part of Gnome-Tweak works. I believe you can install it from the ppa in this article: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html

Comment: I went through all of those steps but I still can't add any themes, the drop down menu is still greyed out and that evil orange triangle is still there! Any other ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

Log out, and click the gear next to your login name: choose Gnome instead of Ubuntu
Then Login
Then the extensions should show up & function properly now.